# Unexpected symbol when concatenate strings in R

Tags: r, disk.frame

I met the following problem.
My dataset "Sales" store as `disk.frame`.
There are two character variables "Item-Entity" and "SBLOC". I want to create another variable concatenated these variables:

```
Sales <- as.disk.frame(Sales) %>%
  mutate("Item-Loc" = paste(as.character(`Item-Entity`), as.character(SBLOC), sep = '--'))
```

Instead of result I got the error message

```
Error in parse(text = sprintf("chunk_fn(.disk.frame.chunk, %s)", args_str)) : 
  <text>:1:37: unexpected '='
1: chunk_fn(.disk.frame.chunk, Item-Loc=
                                        ^
```

If I store my dataset as `data.frame` everything work good.
Moreover, another `mutate` commands with arithmetic calculations under the data work good as well.

Please advise

Comment: You may need backquote

Comment: You need to post something reproducible.  We don't know where the `as.disk.frame` function came from, and we don't have your `Sales` object.

Comment: If `as.disk.frame` came from the `disk.frame` package, then this looks like a bug in that package.  But when I start a newly installed copy, it says "{disk.frame} has been soft-deprecated." and you should use `arrow` instead.